# E11000 duplicate key error collection error mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

ok so basically im getting this error and i dont know whats causing it

```
MongoServerError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.profilemodels index: userID_1 dup key: { userID: "776359374783512608" }
```

i've literally tried dropping indexes and it still didnt work. all that works is when i drop my database/collection and i dont wanna have to do that everytime

my schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
  serverID: { type: String, require: true },
  coins: { type: Number, default: 200 },
  inventory: { type: Object },
  bank: { type: Number },
  bankSpace: { type: Number, default: 10000 },
  bankNotes: { type: Number },
  title: { type: String, default: 'Newbie'},
  badges: { type: String, default: 'None'},
  cPoints: { type: Number}
});

const model = mongoose.model("ProfileModels", profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

the code the error is coming from:

```js
            const cpoints = profileData.cPoints
            if(cpoints < 10000) return message.reply('You don\'t have enough wins for this title!')

            await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    userID: message.author.id,
                    title: 'Coinflipper'
                }
            );
            message.reply('Successfully equipped the **Coinflipper** Title!')
```

im stumped by this error hopefully someone can help

Comment: are you getting any multiple document when you do a simple find query for that userId in your DB, also check whether you have mistankenly connected to different DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed in your schema, the `userID` field has to be unique.

With syntax below, you are telling to mongoose to update FIRST found document with userID that was already used by some other document. It's beacuse in that case first parameter is 'update' part.

```
await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  // update part 
   {
       userID: message.author.id,
       title: 'Coinflipper'
   }
);
```

So to fix it, you have to
set some filtration in the first parameter, and in the second one 'fields to update'. So it will be like

```
  await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
     // filter part
    {
        userID: message.author.id
    },
    // update part 
    {
        title: 'Coinflipper'
    }
);
```

Comment: i didnt know it had like a filter system, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are not using properly the function `findOneAndUpdate(..)`, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Try something like this:

```js
await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
             { userID: message.author.id}, // filter
             { title: 'Coinflipper' } // fields to modify
            );
```